# double click on li open jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an unordered list in this format:

```
  <ul>
    <li><img src="yahoo.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="google.jpg"/></li>
  </ul>
```

What I want is when I double click on any image, a jquery pop up open with full image.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

no one will ever do a double click on an image on a website
but you could setup a clickcounter and `if(clickcounter > 1) doStuff();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul li img").dblclick(function(){

  var src = $(this).attr("src");

  // popup code here..
  // um.. which jquery popup plugin?

});
```

or.. you should try using jQuery plugin for image gallery. try [fancy box](http://fancybox.net/) or [jquery lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

with jquery lightbox, you just call `lightbox()` function

```
$('ul li a').lightBox();
```